# Retrieve name of user from Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am admittedly very new to AD.  I have a dropdown list that I have bound with a list of members within our organization.  My end goal is to find their manager name, but I'm starting with baby steps.

I've done enough searching to get the right result.  I'm having a problem getting the right data (verified by using breakpoints etc) out of the result

```
private void cmbUserList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var userName = cmbUserList.SelectedValue.ToString();
    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher();

    search.Filter = String.Format("(cn={0})", userName);
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName");

    SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

    if (result != null)
    {
        // For now I'm trying to just retrieve their name
        lblManagerName.Text = result.GetDirectoryEntry().Name;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I'm using .net version 4.0

Could someone point me towards retrieving the correct name, and then maybe even a link or resources to pull the manager name?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Sorry good question using 4.0

Comment: Have you ried something like: result.Properties("givenName")(0).ToString() ?

Comment: It says Properties can't be used like a method

Comment: Sorry, that was vb.net. Not sure how it is in C#  result.Properties["givenName"][0].ToString()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem with your code is you are using "(cn={0})", userName. You need to pass fully qualified name like

```
CN=Doe,John,OU=Users,OU=Headquarters,DC=company,DC=net
```

If you only have login ID, then the code below should work

```
DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher("LDAP://RootDSE");
directorySearcher.Filter = "sAMAccountName=" + acctName;
directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("manager");
SearchResult searchResult = directorySearcher.FindOne();
if (searchResult != null)
DirectoryEntry user = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
```

Note that acctName is Windows login ID. If you want to play with AD and check out vearious properties and how they are stored, try dsquery and dsget command line tools. The command below will return a user record based on login id and will display contents of the manager field:

```
dsquery user domainroot -samid "loginid" | dsget user -samid -mgr
```

Comment: this is not true, cn attribute in AD is just full name so for John Smith => cn=John Smith. I fully support looking by sAMAccountName

Comment: @Zilog I believe it's configurable in AD, I've seen "last,first" also.

Comment: Full path you are referring to in your answer is dn (Distinguished Name) not cn, so the query (cn={0}) was / is proper as long as {0} is full name, and it cannot be full path as you suggest. Your suggestion to use sAMAccountName is valid.

Answer (score 0):

helper class and enum

```
public enum ActiveDirectoryObjectClass
{
    Computer,
    User,
    Domain,
    Group,
}

public static class ActiveDirectorySearcher
{
    public static string  GetCurrentDomainName()
    {
        string result;
        using (Domain domain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain())
        {
            result = domain.Name;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(
        ActiveDirectoryObjectClass activeDirectoryObjectClass,
        Func<DirectoryEntry, ActiveDirectoryObjectClass, bool> condition,
        Func<DirectoryEntry, T> selector
        )
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        using (Domain domain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain())
        using (DirectoryEntry root = domain.GetDirectoryEntry())
        {
            string filter = string.Format("(objectClass={0})", activeDirectoryObjectClass);
            using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(filter))
            {
                searcher.SearchRoot = root;
                searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
                using (SearchResultCollection result = searcher.FindAll())
                {
                    foreach (SearchResult item in result)
                    {
                        using (DirectoryEntry entry = item.GetDirectoryEntry())
                        {
                            if (condition(entry, activeDirectoryObjectClass))
                            {
                                list.Add(selector(entry));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

how to use

```
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return ActiveDirectorySearcher.Select(
            ActiveDirectoryObjectClass.User,
            (entry, adObjectClass) => string.Compare(entry.SchemaClassName, adObjectClass.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0,
            _ => new User
                     {
                         Name = _.Name.Substring(3),
                         Domain = ActiveDirectorySearcher.GetCurrentDomainName(),
                     });
    }
```

Note: User in sample - custom class with properties Name, Domain, etc.

Answer (score 0):

to find name and/or manager name:

```
if (sResult != null)
{
    string userName = sResult.Properties["name"][0].ToString();
    string managerDN = sResult.Properties["manager"][0].ToString();

    DirectoryEntry man =  new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://server_name/"+managerDN);
    string managerName = man.Properties["name"][0].ToString();

}
```

server_name can be just domain component of FQDN i.e yourcompany.com, that way it will find catalog server on its own via DNS.

Edit:

I also recomend Active Directory Explorer from Sysinternals. It is great tool for exploring and understanding structure of AD